# "Error: Couldn't find an Opus engine." when trying to play an mp3 file (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am using Heroku to host my app, where I have the following piece of code:

```
if (isReady && message.content === '!play')
{
    isReady = false;
    var voiceChannel = message.member.voiceChannel;
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection =>
    {
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile('./BRODYQUEST.mp3');
        dispatcher.on("end", end => {
            voiceChannel.leave();
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    isReady = true;
}
```

When i type the command, the bot joins my channel but it doesnt play any music. I get this error in the console:

```
2018-04-29T07:00:49.053720+00:00 app[worker.1]: Error: Couldn't find an Opus engine.

2018-04-29T07:00:49.053738+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.exports.guaranteeOpusEngine (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/opus/OpusEngineList.js:30:31)

2018-04-29T07:00:49.053739+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at AudioPlayer.playUnknownStream (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/player/AudioPlayer.js:87:18)

2018-04-29T07:00:49.053741+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at VoiceConnection.playFile (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/voice/VoiceConnection.js:448:24)

2018-04-29T07:00:49.053742+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at voiceChannel.join.then.connection (/app/bot.js:71:40)

2018-04-29T07:00:49.053744+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at <anonymous>

2018-04-29T07:00:49.053745+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have included the error in your question and updated your title so others see immediately what it's about. I also changed some of your sentence structure and removed some fluff, to make the question more clear. If you're unhappy with any of these edits, feel free to modify your question again!

Comment: May I see your GitHub's package.json?

Comment: Sure: https://github.com/datejer/memester/blob/master/package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have succesfully installed `discord.js` but to decode and encode the mp3 file you want to play you must have installed a codec to do that for you:

So you simply install `npm install discord.js node-opus` and you should be fine.

Comment: How do i do that on heroku tho. Im using heroku to host my bot. (and GitHub)

Comment: You should login to your server and after that you type the command in that I write above.

Comment: It says that heruko has node.js so you should able to do this.

Comment: It says that you should first rebuild the `node-gyp`. Just type in: `node-gyp rebuild`

Answer (score 1):

In order to run this, you'll need to have `ytdl-core` installed.

```
npm install --save ytdl-core
```

If you get an error that says 'OPUS_ENGINE_MISSING', you'll need to install one of the opus packages discord.js recommends.

```
npm install --save node-opus
```

If you get an error that says 'FFMPEG not found', this can be resolved by installing ffmpeg.

On Debian / Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

On Windows:

```
npm install ffmpeg-binaries --save
```

Additionally, there have been reports that playing audio in this way from the Ubuntu subsystem offered by Windows 10 does not work.